# How can I get the list of metazones from Zend Framework's Zend_Locale?

Tags: php, zend-framework, timezone

I'm trying to have a list of all the most common time zones for a UI component. By digging in the Zend framework I found that supplementalData.xml (used by the `Zend_Locale` component) has a list of metazones, with prefered TZ database time zone names

```
    <mapTimezones type="metazones">
        <mapZone other="Acre" territory="001" type="America/Rio_Branco"/>
        <mapZone other="Afghanistan" territory="001" type="Asia/Kabul"/>
        <mapZone other="Africa_Central" territory="001" type="Africa/Maputo"/>
        <mapZone other="Africa_Central" territory="BI" type="Africa/Bujumbura"/>
        <mapZone other="Africa_Central" territory="BW" type="Africa/Gaborone"/>
        <mapZone other="Africa_Central" territory="CD" type="Africa/Lubumbashi"/>
        (...)
```

I think that could be a nice fit for my needs and I'd like to have this list extracted.
Rather than hacking my version of library I'd like to know if there is a way to get this list by normal means (there doesn't seem to be a way and this metazones info does not seem to be queried anywhere).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which one you are after, but your best candidate is

```
$locale->getTranslationList('TerritoryToTimezone');
```

where `TerritoryToTimezone` can be exchanged with any of identifiers described in the reference manual for [`Zend_Locale` subchapter Obtaining Localized Data](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.functions.html#zend.locale.getdata).

If none of these give you what you are looking for, you can still [use DOM to parse the XML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: Probably my best bet then. I will extend the `Zend_Locale_Data` class to provide support for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timezone_abbreviations_list(), timezone_identifiers_list()...
Last set of functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)